# How do I run a piped powershell command from command line?

Tags: file, datetime, powershell, command-line

I am trying to run the following powershell command from the windows 7 command line:

```
powershell ls 'C:/path to file/' | ForEach-Object {$_.LastWriteTime=Get-Date}
```

I have encountered several errors.  When I run the above command, I get the error:

```
'ForEach-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

I changed the command to:

```
powershell ls 'C:/My Programs/CPU Analysis/data/test/' | powershell ForEach-Object {$_.LastWriteTime=Get-Date}
```

Now I am getting the error:

```
Property 'LastWriteTime' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists
and is settable.
At line:1 char:17
+ ForEach-Object {$_.LastWriteTime=Get-Date}
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

How can I modify this command to work from the command line?

#### Update

Both solutions are basically saying the same thing, but @Trevor Sullivan has a clearer answer.

Comment: PowerShell *is* a command line. Open a PowerShell window, then type the command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cmd.exe doesn't understand foreach object. Plus, you're trying to split execution across two separate PowerShell processes, which is not going to work in this scenario.

You'll need to run the whole command in PowerShell.

```
powershell "ls 'C:/My Programs/CPU Analysis/data/test/' | ForEach-Object {$_.LastWriteTime = Get-Date}"
```

Comment: if the PS command has quotes? `"`, replace them with single quotes `'`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve..but if you are after files and their last modified time then use this:

```powershell
powershell "ls 'C:\path' | ft name,LastWriteTime"
```

All you have to do is enclose your command in double quotes `"`.

Comment: I did not use the `ft name,LastWriteTime` but I did use the double quotes and it worked.  Thank you!